# Add param curl -d in POSTMAN

Tags: curl, postman

I try to execute  the next CURL .

How can I add the param -d in POSTMAN

```
curl https://core.spreedly.com/v1/gateways.json \
  -u 'Ll6fAtoVSTyVMlJEmtpoJV8S:RKOCG5D8D3fZxDSg504D0IxU2XD4Io5VXmyzdCtTivHFTTSy' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "gateway": {
          "gateway_type": "test"
        }
      }'
```

[PostmanExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHltY.png)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`-d` is POST data.

You need to add your JSON data to the body section of the request and set the request method to `POST`.

E.g.

[image: Postman screenshot with JSON body]

Comment: Elasticsearch gives me an error when I try to send a POST from Postman. The curl at ES is a GET with a -d: curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_store/products/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query" : {
        "constant_score" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "price" : [20, 30]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'

Comment: @NateUni A GET request with data in its body? I don't think so.